# Merge multidimensional array according to conditions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

I have the following arrays:

```
array (size=6)
  'ID' => int 786
  'userID' => int 97291
  'tip_index' => string 'CARS' (length=11)
  'tip_apa' => string 'calda' (length=5)
  'citire' => string '2' (length=1)
  'data' => string '2020-04-21 15:32:49' (length=19)
C:\wamp64\www\test2.php:19:
array (size=6)
  'ID' => int 785
  'userID' => int 97291
  'tip_index' => string 'TRUCKS' (length=9)
  'tip_apa' => string 'calda' (length=5)
  'citire' => string '1' (length=1)
  'data' => string '2020-04-21 15:32:49' (length=19)
C:\wamp64\www\test2.php:19:
array (size=6)
  'ID' => int 784
  'userID' => int 97291
  'tip_index' => string 'MOTORCYCLES' (length=4)
  'tip_apa' => string 'calda' (length=5)
  'citire' => string '1' (length=1)
  'data' => string '2020-04-21 15:32:49' (length=19)
C:\wamp64\www\test2.php:19:
array (size=6)
  'ID' => int 783
  'userID' => int 97291
  'tip_index' => string 'CARS' (length=11)
  'tip_apa' => string 'calda' (length=5)
  'citire' => string '1' (length=1)
  'data' => string '2020-03-21 15:32:44' (length=19)
C:\wamp64\www\test2.php:19:
array (size=6)
  'ID' => int 782
  'userID' => int 97291
  'tip_index' => string 'TRUCKS' (length=9)
  'tip_apa' => string 'calda' (length=5)
  'citire' => string '0' (length=1)
  'data' => string '2020-03-21 15:32:41' (length=19)
C:\wamp64\www\test2.php:19:
array (size=6)
  'ID' => int 781
  'userID' => int 97291
  'tip_index' => string 'MOTORCYCLES' (length=4)
  'tip_apa' => string 'calda' (length=5)
  'citire' => string '0' (length=1)
  'data' => string '2020-03-21 15:32:39' (length=19)
```

I expect output 3 multidimensional arrays like this grouped by `tip_index` and `tip_apa` where I add some custom keys for each `tip_apa` (eg: for `tip_apa = rece` I want to add array `data_iv_rece`,`number_iv_rece`,`data_in_rece`, `number_in_rece`). Each `tip_apa` has the last month date and value and this month date and value like so:

```
array (size=3)
  'CARS' => 
    array (size=2)
      'rece' => 
        array (size=4)
          'data_iv_rece' => string '22.03.2020' (length=10)
          'number_iv_rece' => string '1' (length=1)
          'data_in_rece' => string '22.04.2020' (length=10)
          'number_in_rece' => string '0' (length=1)
      'calda' => 
        array (size=4)
          'data_iv_calda' => string '22.03.2020' (length=10)
          'number_iv_calda' => string '1' (length=1)
          'data_in_calda' => string '22.04.2020' (length=10)
          'number_in_calda' => string '0' (length=1)
  'TRUCKS' => 
    array (size=2)
      'rece' => 
        array (size=4)
          'data_iv_rece' => string '22.03.2020' (length=10)
          'number_iv_rece' => string '1' (length=1)
          'data_in_rece' => string '22.04.2020' (length=10)
          'number_in_rece' => string '0' (length=1)
      'calda' => 
        array (size=4)
          'data_iv_calda' => string '22.03.2020' (length=10)
          'number_iv_calda' => string '1' (length=1)
          'data_in_calda' => string '22.04.2020' (length=10)
          'number_in_calda' => string '0' (length=1)
  'MOTORCYCLES' => 
    array (size=2)
      'rece' => 
        array (size=4)
          'data_iv_rece' => string '22.03.2020' (length=10)
          'number_iv_rece' => string '1' (length=1)
          'data_in_rece' => string '22.04.2020' (length=10)
          'number_in_rece' => string '0' (length=1)
      'calda' => 
        array (size=4)
          'data_iv_calda' => string '22.03.2020' (length=10)
          'number_iv_calda' => string '1' (length=1)
          'data_in_calda' => string '22.04.2020' (length=10)
          'number_in_calda' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Here is what been trying for the last 2 days, without getting any expected output:

```
 $userID   = $_SESSION['ID'];
 $info  = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `indecsi` WHERE `userID` = '$userID'")->fetchAll();
 $arrayInfos = array();
 foreach ($info as $key => $val) 
    {
        $month= date('m',strtotime($val['data']));

        if(date($month < date('m')) && $val['tip_apa'] == 'rece')
        {
            $data_iv_rece = $val['data'];
            $number_iv_rece = $val['citire'];
            $arrayInfos += [ 'data_iv_rece' => $data_iv_rece ];
            $arrayInfos += [ 'number_iv_rece' => $number_iv_rece ];
        }

        if(date($month == date('m')) && $val['tip_apa'] == 'rece')
        {
            $data_in_rece = $val['data'];
            $number_in_rece = $val['citire'];
            $arrayInfos += [ "data_in_rece" => $data_in_rece ];
            $arrayInfos += [ "number_in_rece" => $number_in_rece ];
        }

        if(date($month < date('m')) && $val['tip_apa'] == 'calda')
        {
            $data_iv_calda = $val['data'];
            $number_iv_calda = $val['citire'];
            $arrayInfos += [ 'data_iv_calda' => $data_iv_calda ];
            $arrayInfos += [ 'number_iv_calda' => $number_iv_calda ];
        }

        if(date($month == date('m')) && $val['tip_apa'] == 'calda')
        {
            $data_in_calda = $val['data'];
            $number_in_calda = $val['citire'];
            $arrayInfos += [ "data_in_calda" => $data_in_calda ];
            $arrayInfos += [ "number_in_calda" => $number_in_calda ];
        }
    }
```

And finally trying to get the 3 arrays in a table:

```
 $consum_rece = $number_in_rece - $number_iv_rece;
 $consum_calda = $number_in_calda - $number_iv_calda;
 $table.= "<tr class='text-center'>";
 $table.= "<td>" . str_replace('_', ' ' , $val['tip_index']) . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $arrayInfos['data_in_rece'] . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $arrayInfos['number_in_rece'] . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $arrayInfos['data_iv_rece'] . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $arrayInfos['number_iv_rece'] . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $consum_rece . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $arrayInfos['data_in_calda'] . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $arrayInfos['number_in_calda'] . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $arrayInfos['data_iv_calda'] . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $arrayInfos['number_iv_calda'] . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>" . $consum_calda . "</td>";
 $table.= "<td>-</td>";
 $table.= "</tr>";
```

[image]

Tried multiple things, like `array_push`, `array_merge` , `array_diff` to get to the expected output but no luck. I feel like I am half way there and cant get it right. Any advices, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bit confused by your explanation at first, but I think I found out what is expected to happen.

Let's assume you already have this php array (gathered from MySQL or other place):

```
$all_vehicles = array(
  array(
    'id' => 786,
    'userID' => 9791,
    'tip_index' => 'CARS',
    'tip_apa' => 'calda',
    'citire' => 2,
    'data' => '2020-04-21 15:32:49'
  ),  
  array(
    'id' => 785,
    'userID' => 9791,
    'tip_index' => 'TRUCKS',
    'tip_apa' => 'calda',
    'citire' => 1,
    'data' => '2020-04-21 15:32:49'
  ), 
  array(
    'id' => 784,
    'userID' => 97291,
    'tip_index' => 'MOTORCYCLES',
    'tip_apa' => 'calda',
    'citire' => 1,
    'data' => '2020-04-21 15:32:49'
  ), 
  array(
    'id' => 783,
    'userID' => 97291,
    'tip_index' => 'CARS',
    'tip_apa' => 'calda',
    'citire' => 1,
    'data' => '2020-03-21 15:32:44'
  ), 
  array(
    'id' => 782,
    'userID' => 97291,
    'tip_index' => 'TRUCKS',
    'tip_apa' => 'calda',
    'citire' => 0,
    'data' => '2020-03-21 15:32:41'
  ), 
  array(
    'id' => 781,
    'userID' => 97291,
    'tip_index' => 'MOTORCYCLES',
    'tip_apa' => 'calda',
    'citire' => 0,
    'data' => '2020-03-21 15:32:39'
  ),
);
```

My suggestion would be to roll through the array and update the required values. I have automated it to remove the ifs and elses by adding "data_in_" - Value.

Then add them to multidimensional array to split between Cars, Trucks and Motorcycles.

```
$ordered_vehicles = array();
foreach($all_vehicles as $val)
{
    $month= date('m',strtotime($val['data']));

    if($month <= date('m') && in_array($val['tip_apa'],array('rece','calda')))
    {
        $data = date('d.m.Y',strtotime($val['data']));
        // Convert the data in the required format DD.MM.YYYY
        $number = $val['citire'];

        $val['data_in_'.$val['tip_apa']] =  $data;
        $val['number_in_'.$val['tip_apa']] =  $number;
    }

    $ordered_vehicles[$val['tip_index']][$val['tip_apa']][] = $val;
}
```

The expected outcome would be multidimensional array with 3 child arrays - Cars, Trucks and Motorcycles. Each of them have multiple arrays inside with the required data.

It is looking like that in my case:

```
Array
(
    [CARS] => Array
        (
            [calda] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 786
                            [userID] => 9791
                            [tip_index] => CARS
                            [tip_apa] => calda
                            [citire] => 2
                            [data] => 2020-04-21 15:32:49
                            [data_in_calda] => 21.04.2020
                            [number_in_calda] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 783
                            [userID] => 97291
                            [tip_index] => CARS
                            [tip_apa] => calda
                            [citire] => 1
                            [data] => 2020-03-21 15:32:44
                            [data_in_calda] => 21.03.2020
                            [number_in_calda] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [TRUCKS] => Array
        (
            [calda] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 785
                            [userID] => 9791
                            [tip_index] => TRUCKS
                            [tip_apa] => calda
                            [citire] => 1
                            [data] => 2020-04-21 15:32:49
                            [data_in_calda] => 21.04.2020
                            [number_in_calda] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 782
                            [userID] => 97291
                            [tip_index] => TRUCKS
                            [tip_apa] => calda
                            [citire] => 0
                            [data] => 2020-03-21 15:32:41
                            [data_in_calda] => 21.03.2020
                            [number_in_calda] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [MOTORCYCLES] => Array
        (
            [calda] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 784
                            [userID] => 97291
                            [tip_index] => MOTORCYCLES
                            [tip_apa] => calda
                            [citire] => 1
                            [data] => 2020-04-21 15:32:49
                            [data_in_calda] => 21.04.2020
                            [number_in_calda] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 781
                            [userID] => 97291
                            [tip_index] => MOTORCYCLES
                            [tip_apa] => calda
                            [citire] => 0
                            [data] => 2020-03-21 15:32:39
                            [data_in_calda] => 21.03.2020
                            [number_in_calda] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

You can after that print and alter the data as wished. 
Please mention below if I`m missing something in the process. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. It's a step forward. I'll test a little bit and let you know.

Comment: @BogdanC I found I missed to split the Cars/Trucks.. array into calda and rece. I have updated my comment.

Comment: Based on your answer I managed to get my table right. Just a few adds to the code and all good! God bless you!

Comment: @BogdanC Glad you made it.